# Div hover changes only when hover top part of the div

Tags: html, background, hover

Live link here
http://soloveich.com/pr1-1/

For some reason, div hover changes only when mouse goes over the part, that's on top of the grey content background. 
When it hovers on lower part- nothing changes

```
 <li><a class="ml" href="http://soloveich.com/pr1-1/?page_id=66"><div class="tabs1"><div id="t1">
    </div></div>
    </a></li>
```

css code

```
#t1 {
height: 519px;
width: 271px;
background-image: url(images/t1.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#t1:hover {
background-image: url(images/t1r.png);
}
```

didn't put all 4 of them here, since it's all the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#cnt1` element is over the divs, and block the hover action. 
You must play with z-index, and positioning... Two less reputation to make a comment, sry :).

**UPDATE**
Sorry, now I'm not sure about that. But You should try to run tFirefox, right click this div, run inspect element and then click the 3D view icon (top right). Then everything should be clarified.

**OK I know**
You must apply the hover effect to the first child of the whole thing. Div is inside a, a is inside li. So `li:hover` is an answer I think. The background should be also applied to the `li` element. Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok :). Remember that if the z-index property is the same for two elements, then their HTML order decide which one is top. And z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).